# Is there a way to save a "." file using NSSavePanel without MacOS warning me?

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I'm working on a cocoa project. My project uses a preferences menu, and includes the option to save a set of preferences as a "." file (hidden files like .rvmrc or .vimrc). The problem is that after bringing up the NSSavePanel and clicking Save the system pops up and reminds me that "." is reserved for the system, which isn't very cool.

Is there some way to prevent the OS from firing that prompt?

Thanks!

Comment: I took out the "Ruby" tag; this doesn't have anything to do with Ruby.

Comment: Is "." the entire file name or file name starts with a "."?

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean dot files like .rvmrc or .vimperatorrc . I guess that wasn't clear, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass or make a category of NSSavePanel and override

```
-[NSSavePanel _legalNameCheck:]
```

AFAIK, checking for the dot name is all that routine does.

Comment: It’s worth noting that overriding framework methods via categories is neither recommended nor guaranteed to be deterministic. Also, methods whose names start with an underscore are private methods, so overriding `_legalNameCheck:` will likely prevent the application from being accepted at the Mac App Store.

Comment: Yes, sorry, should have noted that. This is an internal method and might not keep working across OS X updates. Also, you're targeting app store then this might be an issue too.

Comment: Hmm these are both problems... Does this mean that one of the requirements of being accepted on the mac store is that your app must remind people about the significance of "." files? The app I'm working on is for programmers who will never profit from this warning...

Comment: If you're working on a dev tool, then don't bother being on the App Store. Devs know how to find apps "the old fashioned way" ;)